# c++ passing by reference in recursion

Tags: c++, c++11, boolean, binary-tree, pass-by-reference

```
bool roottoleafsumequaltox(BinaryTreenode<int>* root, int &x)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        return (x==0);
    }
    else
    {
     bool ans = false;
     x = x - root->data;

     if(x == 0 && root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
     {
       return true;
     }

     if(root->left)
      ans = ans || roottoleafsumequaltox(root->left, x);

     if(root->right)
      ans = ans || roottoleafsumequaltox(root->right, x);

     return ans;
   }
}
```

It has to return whether the root to leaf sum is equal to a given number x. I think the problem lies in passing by reference and I am not able detect it...
It always gives false as the answer, even if it is true!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understan what do you want but I suspect the problem is that you modify `x`

```
x= x- root->data;
```

so, when you pass `x` to `roottoleafsumequaltox()`

```
ans= ans || roottoleafsumequaltox(root->left, x);
ans = ans || roottoleafsumequaltox(root->right, x);
```

you pass a `x` with a modified value

I suppose you could avoid to modify `x` and write your `if` in this way

```
if( (x == root->data) && (root->left == nullptr) && (root->right == nullptr) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem is with passing by reference. 
`x` value just keeps on decreasing with each node traversal.

Just get rid of reference passing, and then update:

```
roottoleafsumequaltox(root->left/right, (x - root->data))
```

and check out for 
`(leaf_node->data == x)`.

Make sure, for optimization, you don't go and check right childtree as well if you have already found that one of the route from root(*or any other node*) to leaf gives sum == `x`(*at that position*).